# Running a ssh command inside Mathematica

Tags: linux, ssh, wolfram-mathematica

Lately I've been trying to run a shell ssh command from a Mathematica notebook. I tried several suggested methods with no positive outcome. My search to an answer lead me to the following result:

`RunProcess[$SystemShell, All, "
  ssh <login>@<server>
  exit
  "]`

but this gives a following error

`<|"ExitCode" -> 127, "StandardOutput" -> "",
 "StandardError" ->
  "ssh: /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0/SystemFiles/Libraries/\
Linux-x86-64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available \
(required by ssh)
  ssh: /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0/SystemFiles/Libraries/\
Linux-x86-64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available \
(required by ssh)
  ssh: relocation error: ssh: symbol EVP_aes_128_ctr, version \
OPENSSL_1.0.1 not defined in file libcrypto.so.1.0.0 with link time \
reference
  "|>`

do you have an idea how to fix it?

P.S. My overall goal is to import and export data between external server and Mathematica notebook.

Comment: This is still a 'thing' with version 11.3 on Unix. Trying to call ffmpeg results in "version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found" because it is trying to get it from the copy of libz.so in the MMa directory. Even forcing LD_LIBRARY_PATH doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Łukasz Gładczuk suggestion should work, but there is a better way to accomplish this.

RunProcess provides a ProcessEnvironment option that allows you to set environment variables for your process. The default value is Inherited, which means the environment variables are inherited from Wolfram Language, which is what is causing library problems.

Run `echo $PATH` in a terminal to find your path, then use:

```
RunProcess[{"ssh", "user@server"}, ProcessEnvironment -> <|"PATH" -> yourpath|>]
```

where `yourpath` is your path, as a string.

Answer (score 2):

I found that Mathematica forces library dependencies. If I use ldd /usr/bin/ssh command in terminal I obtain following output:

`linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffb31fe000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f2a309a7000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f2a305cd000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f2a303c8000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f2a301af000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f2a2ff94000)
    libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007f2a2fd4d000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2a2f987000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f2a2f749000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2a30e87000)
    libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007f2a2f47d000)
    libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007f2a2f24e000)
    libcom_err.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007f2a2f04a000)
    libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007f2a2ee3e000)
    libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007f2a2ec3a000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f2a2ea1b000)`

but doing the same in Mathematica:

`RunProcess[$SystemShell, All, "
  ldd /usr/bin/ssh
  exit
  "]`

gives a different dependence on:

`libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f30fbe3c000)
libz.so.1 => /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libz.so.1 (0x00007f30fba20000)`

My solution was to replace the file `/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/10.0/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libcrypto.so.1.0.0` with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0`

this is probably not the best way, but works.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting example / possible solution. When I try to run `ffmpeg` from MMa (11.3, Ubuntu 17)

```
In[16]:= RunProcess["ffmpeg"]
Out[16]= <|ExitCode->1,StandardOutput->,StandardError->/usr/bin/ffmpeg: /usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/11.3/SystemFiles/Libraries/Linux-x86-64/libz.so.1: version `ZLIB_1.2.9' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng16.so.16)|>
```

it's trying to use the `libz.so` from the Mathematica path (as observed by @Łukasz above). Simply running with an *empty* `ProcessEnvironment` works?!

```
In[17]:= RunProcess["ffmpeg",ProcessEnvironment-><||>]
Out[17]= <|ExitCode -> 1, StandardOutput -> , StandardError ->
 ffmpeg version 3.3.4-2 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers                                                          built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu2)
```

which is nice/interesting.